# Send Mail Automatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks

Few days ago I have a website in which i send mail automatically by using Task Scheduler.
I have Created a console based application in it and send mail using task Scheduler at regular interval. But Now the site owner is moving that site from virtual hosting to shared hosting.
And they are not allowing to schedule task. Neither they are providing Sql Server agent and not allowing to Create Window Services so what option i have to send mails at regular interval.
and also i have created that site like a year ago so it will be difficult to make much changes in that site.
Can anyone suggest me what option i have to send mails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244920/ways-of-scheduling-tasks-without-writing-windows-scheduler-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: for the mail part, just use the same code, and set up the [`<mailSettings>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `web.config` file... then, you can even use [Google to send emails](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server). If you want other SMTP, I use [Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com) (up to 12000 mails a month it's for free).